# Stopping fixed position element overlapping footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a two column layout (content + sidebar), sidebar is very long (past the fold), so when you scroll through down the page, the content div follows. Content is fixed position and can get taller with more content. Problem is when you scroll all the way down towards the footer, the content div overlaps the footer content. How can I have the content div not overlap? I'm using some js to achieve the scroll effect. Any help would be great, thank you!

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 230) {
        $('.content').css({position: 'fixed', top: '20px'});
    } else {
        $('.content').css({position: 'relative', top: 0});
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: "sidebar is very long, when you scroll through the sidebar content div follows"? they should be called wise versa then, IMHO.